# [Custom field template plugin] Upload limited to 20 inputs file

Tags: plugins, customization, templates

am running the [CFT](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/) plugin version 1.9.2 on a 3.1.3 wordpress site and in the admin i did set up 30 input file fields related to a custom post type. It all works fine until the 21st field (and beyond) that does not save any file (small picture) that is selected.

I did a local test on wamp, and it all works fine, all the 30 fields are saving (and displaying) well the pictures.

I did another test online (different server) on a test installation. I uploaded the database used locally and all the files, checked the site and the post is displaying well the pictures: [link](http://k-win.fr/wptest/?cpt-project=project-test) and has obviously all 30 saved in the admin.

So after that i tried to create a new post on this test site and uploaded the pictures from the admin and bam there goes the same problem, stuck at 20: [link](http://k-win.fr/wptest/?cpt-project=test-2).

The media upload works fine by the admin works fine, even with high res pics.

Here's the beginning of my template's content in the CFT admin:

```
[project-introduction]
type = textarea
label = Introdução
cols = 50
rows = 6

[p-img-1]
type = file
label = Imagem projeto #1 (capa)

[p-img-2]
type = file
label = Imagem projeto #2

[p-img-3]
type = file
label = Imagem projeto #3
```

I also tried to add the `blank = true` to my `type= file` fields but didnt seem to help.

I'd be glad to have your point of view on this cos am stuck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like it's a php configuration setting "max_file_uploads" rather than a wp problem. Support says i gotta add " ini_set (max_file_upload, xxx )" at the beginning of my script. Question is, where is this script? And is there a way to add this within the functions.php theme file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update, just got the problem back and found a 'real solution, to update the php.ini file at the root of the site with this: `max_file_uploads = 100`

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I divided my pictures into 3 templates and in the post admin i just have to load them with the drop-down menu. The value of "max_file_uploads" is still stuck at 20 but for now it's the best solution i found.